# Android: Error Rss Reader

Tags: android, rss

I have a little problem on my rss reader app.
Practically when I select a news category, list news remains the same.
in debug mode , with breakpoint, everythings is correct, without breakpoint the error persist.
Could be that I need to implement a sleep inside rss parser or asynctask?
This is an example about log when I try to change category:

```js
09-15 18:52:57.022  29287-29420/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag D/URL ASYNK﹕ [url=http://www.cosenzachannel.it/category/s8-sport/c102-news-brutium-cosenza/feed/]CosenzaChannel.it &#187; News Brutium Cosenza[/url]
09-15 18:52:57.090  29287-29308/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-15 18:52:57.090  29287-29308/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa43ab020, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-15 18:53:00.469  29287-29299/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5412(777KB) AllocSpace objects, 10(160KB) LOS objects, 17% free, 19MB/23MB, paused 5.964ms total 65.218ms
09-15 18:53:37.422  29287-29347/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag D/URL ASYNK﹕ [url=http://www.cosenzachannel.it/category/s8-sport/c43-nuoto/feed]CosenzaChannel.it &#187; Nuoto[/url]
09-15 18:53:37.493  29287-29308/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-15 18:53:37.493  29287-29308/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c931a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-15 18:53:37.701  29287-29308/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa467ee80 (ListView) with handle 0xa4343780
09-15 18:53:39.521  29287-29299/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.604ms
09-15 18:53:39.546  29287-29299/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4536(600KB) AllocSpace objects, 15(952KB) LOS objects, 15% free, 22MB/26MB, paused 10ms total 72.815ms
09-15 18:53:54.405  29287-29420/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag D/URL ASYNK﹕ [url=http://www.cosenzachannel.it/category/s8-sport/c40-cinque/feed]CosenzaChannel.it &#187; News Brutium Cosenza[/url]
09-15 18:53:54.491  29287-29308/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-15 18:53:54.491  29287-29308/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa4391640, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-15 18:53:55.628  29287-29287/francescoperfetti.mamba.it.cosenzachannelapp_nofrag I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: Update : with old joomla rss app runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

update:  This would be the cause of problem:

```js
Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1713(249KB) AllocSpace objects, 25(1981KB) LOS objects, 4% free, 41MB/43MB, paused 20.467ms total 29.673ms
```